# С прописной или строчной месяц рамадан?

Tags: прописная-строчная

В соответствии с современными нормами русского языка, названия религиозных праздников и постов пишутся с прописной буквы. Отсюда следует, что если речь о мусульманском посте, который завершается праздником Курбан-байрам, то он будет с прописной: пост Рамадан. С этим все понятно.

Но как быть, если речь идет о названии месяца мусульманского календаря? По правилам **любые месяцы любого календаря пишутся со строчной.** Если май, июнь, июль или даже какой-нибудь термидор мы пишем со строчной, то и рамадан следует тоже писать со строчной, как и остальные месяцы мусульманского календаря (мухаррам, сафар и т. д.)

Чтобы два раза не вставать, сразу отмечу, что академические источники ("Прописная или строчная" Лопатина 2011 г. и одноименный справочник Розенталя 2005 г.) не разделяют месяц рамадан и пост Рамадан, что, на мой взгляд, странно, и рекомендуют писать все с прописной.

С прописной или строчной рамадан в следующих предложениях?

1. В Кувейте раскрыта ячейка ИГ, планировавшая серию терактов в период священного для мусульман месяца *рамадан*.
2. Поездки начнутся после окончания месяца мусульманского календаря *рамадан*.
3. В Турции рост цен на товары продолжился в период мусульманского поста в месяц *рамадан*.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его [как принятый](/help/accepted-answer) (галочка рядом с ответом).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

По-моему,во всех примерах вкладывается именно религиозное значение месяца, значит, с прописной буквы. Это же религиозный календарь, как в православном Пасхальная неделя, Фомина неделя.

В Кувейте раскрыта ячейка ИГ, планировавшая серию терактов в период священного для мусульман месяца Рамадан.-даже слово "священный" имеется.

Поездки начнутся после окончания месяца мусульманского календаря Рамадан. - речь тоже о религиозном месяце, а не обычном календарном.

В Турции рост цен на товары продолжился в период мусульманского поста в месяц Рамадан. - упоминание о посте, тоже мусульманское понятие.

Со строчной было бы такое сопоставление: шёл конец мая (рамадан).

Comment: Мусульманский календарь, как и любой другой, служит для счисления дней, недель, месяцев, лет. В некоторых странах именно он - официальный. Некоторые месяцы этого календаря мусульмане считают священными. Но разве это причина, чтобы писать название священных месяцев с большой буквы? Тем более, ничем не отличается "месяц рамадан"  от "месяца мусульманского календаря рамадан".

Comment: М_Г, не совсем понял "...месяц рамадан" от "месяца мусульманского календаря рамадан".

Comment: У них весь месяц считается праздничным, этим и оправдывается прописная.

Comment: @Серж (1) Если Вы согласны в правилом: месяцы - со строчной, праздники - с прописной, то

Comment: (2) В мусульманском календаре 12 месяцев, часть из них имеет статус священных. Указание на то, что месяц принадлежит мусульманскому календарю ("...после окончания месяца мусульманского календаря (Р?)амадан"), не является основанием писать его с большой буквы, в этом предложении даже нет указания на особый статус рамадана. (2) Даже если есть указание на особый статус месяца рамадан, он в первую очередь - календарный месяц, поэтому и "месяц рамадан" и "священный месяц рамадан" - со строчной. (3) Праздник (пост) имеет то же название Рамадан, он (по принятому нами правилу) пишется с прописной.

Comment: @ М_Г, даже в словарь( Кузнецов) не разделяет пост и месяц  и предлагает писать с прописной. Праздник называется Рамадан, а поскольку в этот месяц люди соблюдают пост, вследствие этого в народе слово Р. употребляется часто и всмысле мусульманского поста.

Comment: Т. е. получается название праздника берет название не от поста, а пост берет название от праздника. Поэтому прописная.

Answer (score 1):

Рамадан – это священный и главный месяц мусульман. В это время  начинается пост, соблюдать который предписано практически всем.  Пост также называется «Рамадан», как и название месяца.

**Поэтому в текстах надо различать название месяца календаря (строчная буква) и название священного поста (прописная буква).**

**Примеры**

Сейчас здесь **рамадан**, то есть пост. Целый месяц правоверные не могут есть до заката солнца, курить, нюхать цветы, а уж о женщинах нечего и говорить. [В. А. Каверин. Перед зеркалом (1965-1970)]

**В Рамадан** я ходил как во сне, слонялся по базару, полупустому утром и начинающему пополняться к вечеру. [Александр Иличевский. Перс (2009)]

[Школа арабского языка | nuruliman.ru](http://nuruliman.ru/archives/325)

Нормы правописания имён и терминов, часто встречающихся в исламских текстах

2.2.6. Со строчной буквы пишутся все заимствованные слова, обозначающие **понятия обиходной жизни мусульманина,** – названия месяцев мусульманского календаря (включая священные), молитвенных действий, статусы поступков и т. п.: рамадан, мухаррам, азан, такбир, фард, макрух, харам, закят.